# How can i blackbox code for a part in chisel?

Tags: chisel, black-box

Because we can't generate always `@(negedge clock or posedge capture)` to chisel. Instead of using blacbox resource to blacbox a file, how can I blackbox one line code `always @(negedge clock or posedge capture)`

```
  if (capture)
    out <= 1'b0;
  else
  begin
    if (enable)
      out <= in;
  end
```

Answer (score 1):

There is some documentation on using black boxes in the [Chisel3 wiki](https://github.com/freechipsproject/chisel3/wiki/BlackBoxes). And there are a number of examples in chisel3/src/test/scala/chiselTests e.g.[chiselTests/BlackBoxImpl.scala](https://github.com/freechipsproject/chisel3/blob/master/src/test/scala/chiselTests/BlackBoxImpl.scala).

Do you have questions about how these examples work or is there some functionality you are seeking that you are not finding?